# How to iterate over a list of lists using python's map() function

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over a list of lists to change the data type of each value to a string (if it's not already).

Currently I'm trying to do a

```
data = list(map(str, data))
```

but it's just wrapping each list in quotes instead of each element inside each list in quotes.

How do I go about doing this using map?

Comment: What is your input and what is your expected output? str will convert the list to it's string representation.., if you want to create strings from list of strings do `map("".join, data)`

Comment: do you want to avoid a for loop?

Comment: Are you set on map?  A list comprehension is a better choice than map here.

Comment: if you are set on using map, then try this `list(map(lambda x: list(map(str, x)), l))` as i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 2):

if you have a 2d list like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
```

and you want to apply a function to the element, you have to loop through:

```
data = list(list(map(str, inner)) for inner in data)
```

or without map:

```
data = [[str(item) for item in inner] for inner in data]
```

or with regular for loops:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[i])):
        data[i][j] = str(data[i][j]
```

Comment: You've got redundant square brackets in your solution. Both of your suggestions can either be written using nested `list()` calls or nested comprehensions, but there's no reason to mix the two. Also most, if not all container type functions accept generators, e.g., `list(list(map(str, inner) for inner in data))`!

Comment: couple of pointers, why use a list on top of a list comprehension? its redundant.

Comment: @ddejohn fixed the redundant brackets. Thanks for the suggestion, learned something new

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh, its still not fixed. just fyi.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal can you elaborate more? I've removed the generators where `list` was used. Couldn't remove any more.

Comment: yea i see that now, deleted my second point

Comment: no i mean you are mixing the generator and the list comprehension in the second appraoch. just use `[[str(item) for item in inner] for inner in data]`

Comment: Ooh ... I remember having an issue with this. Not entirely sure what it was, but I remember having to use `list` on top of the generator. It's possible it was some copying stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 ways of doing what you want -

#### Using standard nested list comprehensions

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]

[[str(i) for i in j] for j in data]
```

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

#### Using nested map

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]

list(map(lambda x: list(map(str, x)), data))
```

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

#### Nested for loops

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]

output = []
for i in data:
    sublist = []
    for j in i:
        sublist.append(str(j))
    output.append(sublist)
    
output
```

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```